# Trying to output 2 objects from an array using a sort-object on one of them

Tags: arrays, powershell, datetime

I have an array of scheduled tasks and their respective run times. I want to sort the array into next-run order but I cannot select both the task name and run time for output.

I get the scheduled tasks and run times from the remote computer like this:

```
$Array = @(Invoke-Command -CN blahcomputernameblah {schtasks.exe /query /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select "Next Run Time" , TaskName)
```

The result is like this:

```
Next Run Time        TaskName
-------------        --------
6/3/2019 8:00:00 PM  \Start Banana
6/3/2019 4:00:00 PM  \Start Apple
6/5/2019 9:30:00 AM  \Start Orange
6/3/2019 10:15:00 PM \Stop Banana
6/3/2019 6:15:00 PM  \Stop Apple
6/5/2019 11:45:00 AM \Stop Orange
```

The next task to run will be  `\Start Apple at 6/3/2019 4:00:00 PM`.

So I want so sort that array based on next run time and select -first 1 but I can only get the next run time without the task name. I am converting the date and time string to DateTime for the sort action:

```
$Array | %{[DateTime] $_."Next Run Time"} | sort | select -First 1
```

But I do not know how to add the TaskName to the output

Any help please?

Comment: instead of the `ForEach {} | Sort-Object`, use a calculated property in a Sort-Object`. that will let you convert to datetime & sort on that while leaving the object itself as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can create a propert y into your select like this :

```
schtasks.exe /query /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select @{N="DateRunTime";E={[DateTime]$_."Next Run Time"}}, TaskName | sort DateRunTime | select -First 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As the output of schtasks.exe is localized I suggest to use the equivalent PowerShell cmdlets directly to avoid the [datetime] conversion firsthand.

```
 Get-ScheduledTask | 
  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | 
   Where-Object NextRunTime | 
    Sort-Object NextRunTime | 
     Select-Object TaskName,NextRunTime -First 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the PowerShell cmdlets for managing scheduled tasks produce inaccurate data against remote machines in different timezones, this is a known bug open since at least 2017. This is why I am forced to use alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing what you need with the help of the Task Scheduler scripting objects and their APIs. Complete information can be obtained from the [Task Scheduler Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-scheduler-reference). The following script demonstrates how to do this.

```
$schedsvc = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$schedsvc.Connect()
$fq = New-Object System.Collections.Queue
$fq.Enqueue($schedsvc.GetFolder('\'))
$tc = while ( $fq.Count -gt 0 ) {
  $f = $fq.Dequeue()
  $f.GetFolders(0) | ForEach-Object { $fq.Enqueue($_) }
  $f.GetTasks(0) | Select-Object Name, NextRunTime
}
$tc | Where-Object { $_.NextRunTime -gt (Get-Date)} |
  Sort-Object -Property NextRunTime | Select-Object -First 1 |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Output:**

```
Name                                  NextRunTime
----                                  -----------
Opera scheduled Autoupdate 1542563984 02.06.2019 22:17:10
```